# Mongoose validation error but I put documents correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Please take a look at my code. I am having a validation error but I am quite sure that I put my documents on the correct format.

**MY MODEL**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var orderSchema = new Schema({
    userPurchased: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
    products: [
        {
            product: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'products' },
            size: { type: String, required: true },
            quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
            subTotal: { type: Number, required: true }
        }
    ],
    totalQuantity: { type: Number },
    totalPrice: { type: Number },
    otherShipAd: { type: String },
    modeOfPayment: { type: String },
    paidStatus: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('orders', orderSchema);
```

**MY ROUTE**

```
ordersRouter.route('/placeOrder')
        .post(function (req, res) {
            var body = req.body;
            console.log(req.body);
            var orderItem = {
                userPurchased: body.userId,
                products: [{
                    product: body._id,
                    size: body.size,
                    quantity: body.quantity,
                    subTotal: body.subTotal
                }],
                totalQuantity: body.totalQuantity,
                totalPrice: body.totalPrice,
                otherShipAd: body.customAdd,
                modeOfPayment: body.modeOfPayment
            };
            Orders.create(orderItem, function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        });
```

**MY JSON OBJECT FROM POSTMAN**

```
{
    "userPurchased": "5887f303c58a953360fe2759",
    "products": [{
        "product": "58466e8e734d1d2b0ceeae00",
        "size": "m",
        "quantity": 3,
        "subTotal": 1197
    },
    {
        "product": "58466e8e734d1d2b0ceeae00",
        "size": "l",
        "quantity": 3,
        "subTotal": 1197
    }],
    "totalQuantity": 6,
    "totalPrice": 2394,
    "otherShipAd": "",
    "modeOfPayment": "BDO"
}
```

Please see my error stack trace
[image]

EDIT: Result of req.body
[image]

What am I doing wrong in here? I'm stuck.

Comment: what are you sending in the POST request? Tell me the rsult of `console.log(req.body)`.

Comment: edited my question to show the result of the request body

Comment: how are you importing Order ? Are you storing them in var Order or var order. See you have used "Orders.create".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing mistake while creating a new`order`. Look at the `contents` of `req.body` and look what you are passing to the `orders` object.

**Try this:**

```
var orderItem = new Orders();
orderItem.userPurchased=body.userId;
//for each products item, push it to orderItem.products
body.products.forEach(function(product,index)
{
    orderItem.products.push({
        product: product.product,
        size: product.size,
        quantity: product.quantity,
        subTotal: product.subTotal
    }); 
});
orderItem.totalQuantity=body.totalQuantity;
orderItem.totalPrice=body.totalPrice;
orderItem.otherShipAd=body.customAdd;
orderItem.modeOfPayment=body.modeOfPayment;

Orders.save(function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: I already know that my problem is pushing the array of items from my req.body to the varialble. This is what I am looking for. BTW what is the use of index paramerter in forEach?

Comment: that is optional in this case,you can omit index here. just `forEach(function(product){})` will work.

Comment: Accept the answer and upvote it, if it helped you solve your issue.

Comment: That makes it clear! Thank you. Accepted you're answer and upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have asked the same question about the array in a separate post - you should avoid duplicating your questions.

The answer is shorter -> you have no need of processing your req.body as it matches the required schema of your model. This should work fine:

```
ordersRouter.route('/placeOrder')
    .post(function (req, res) {

        Orders.create(req.body, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;

            // send success message back
        });
    });
```

Comment: sorry. I think my question here is why am I having a validation error, and on the second one is how to process an array of objects in the req.body. If that would be a duplicate then its my fault. BTW thanks for this. Didn't think that this can also be done. I will try this and let you know.